# How to fix localhost refused to connect on Windows 10 Wamp server and Xampp?

Tags: php, html, mysql, apache

I've installed WAMP Server on Windows 10 and it was working fine. But when I try to load **localhost** today it gives me **refused to connect** error. I've read some questions on Stack Overflow and tried their answers but no luck.

- Re-installed wamp (also tried xampp. non of these work)
- IIS is off
- Web Development.. thing in services is not running.
- Tried **netstat -aon** and port 80 PID is same as wampapache64 process.
- changed listening port to 81 in httpd.conf in wamp => apache =>
- Cleared browser cache
- Wamp icon is **green**
- Can't connect using 127.0.0.1

Nothing works.

Screenshots:

[image]

[image: PID is 7724]

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: did you add the line into your hosts file?

Comment: In the bottom right corner of your screen, is the WAMP logo showing green, amber or red?

Comment: it's green @MarkOverton

Comment: @treyBake what is the line please?

Comment: @Chethiya_K in C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc -> there is a file called hosts. Add `127.0.0.1 yoursite.local` to the bottom and boom! You should be in business

Comment: We need more infos. What is the content of C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts. Do you ping localhost ? Do you ping 127.0.0.1 ? Can you connect to your site with 127.0.0.1 ?

Comment: @treyBake you mean like this?  # 127.0.0.1 localhost

Comment: @Chethiya_K without the hashtag^^ :)

Comment: 0.0.0.0 means Apache is bound to all IPs instead of just localhost (127.0.0.1).  Try browsing to the IP address of the machine.

Comment: @hogren can't connect with 127.0.0.1. and screenshots are updated. could you please check that?

Comment: @ChrisFNZ not working :/

Comment: @treyBake not working bro :/

Comment: are you able to just go to localhost and see the default landing page for it?

Comment: What does the Listen line of your httpd.conf file show?

Comment: @treyBake Nope. just the **This site can’t be reached** message

Comment: @Chethiya_K then you have a bigger issue at hand, your service isn't running properly

Comment: @ChrisFNZ 
Listen 0.0.0.0:80
Listen [::0]:80

Comment: Can you please change it to Listen 127.0.0.1:80

Comment: @treyBake you mean **wampapache64** service?

Comment: And then restart Apache httpd service afterwards and then try browse to http://localhost

Comment: @ChrisFNZ I tried. Not working ;(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- I will assume the wamp icon in the system tray is green. I think you should start tracing the root cause from the apache error/access log.
- Try change the http port to 8080 and access localhost:8080. left click the wamp icon in the taskbar, go to apache > httpd.conf and edit this file: change "listen to port ..  80" to 8080.
- Try the hosts file with only the initial records and test.

  `127.0.0.1 localhost`
  `::1 localhost`
- If you are facing the error from the apache errors log file

> (OS 10038)An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket.  : AH00332: winnt_accept: getsockname error on listening socket, is IPv6 available?

then do the following:
* Run 'command prompt' as administrator and run the command `netsh winsock reset` . and restart the PC.

- Skype default port is 80 and this might be having a conflict .. try to change it from Skype options.
- Finally make sure the antivirus or any firewall you are having is not blocking your application requests.

Answer (score 0):

firstly, uninstall wampp as well as xampp server from your PC. Also delete the wampp/xampp folders in C drive.

then install wampserver 2.0i from the link below-
[wampserver 2.0i](https://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/files/WampServer%202/WampServer%202.0/WampServer2.0i.exe/download)

after installation, start wamppserver and try to open localhost in chrome browser.
if localhost doesnt work, then try localhost:80
hope it helps!!